# SwiftUI on Mac Catalyst - Edit List with Slider

Tags: listview, slider, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I got a slider in a list:

[image: img1]

I enable the move edit mode:

```
.onMove { source, destination in
    // ...                     
}
```

[image: img2]

Tho now I can't move the slider...

[image: img3]

For now I disable the move like this:

```
.moveDisabled({
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    return true
    #else
    return false
    #endif
}())
```

Tho that removes all move functionality... I only want to disable the drag.

Is there a way to read the edit button state? To dynamically change `.moveDisabled(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to manage edit mode manually, thus having possibility to track it is real state. Please see below in code idea how to manage it. The code is simplified, w/o real actions, etc., just to demo how to disable move being in `.active` edit mode.

*Note: using default `@Environment(\.editMode)` does not work for this purpose, at least in my Xcode 11.2. So it is set as binding to local state, so it is tracked and with List and with our code.*

```
struct TestEditWithSliderInList: View {
    @State var value = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: 5)
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { i in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Slider \(i)")
                        Slider(value: self.$value[i], in: 0...100)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: {_ in })
                .onMove(perform: {(_,_) in })
                .moveDisabled(editMode == .active ? false : true)
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.editMode = (self.editMode == .active ? .inactive : .active)
                }
            }) {
                Text(self.editMode == .active ? "Done" : "Edit")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! this method solves the problem! I was also able to read the `editMode` `Environment `, so could still use the `EditButton`.